# Core video - displaylink I need help interpreting CVTimeStamp

Tags: opengl, quicktime, core-video, .mov

Core video experts, I'm creating a custom video player for .mov files. I have the .mov parser working and using the QTCoreVideo101 sample I am trying to play video.

The problem I have is the display link getFrameForTime I don't know how the time values can be used to find the correct frame.

The values contained in CVTimeStamp don't make any sense to me. Below is a sample of the values requested for a 1 second video. Can anyone explain how I use these values to find the correct frame in the .mov file?

First three requests - value of CVTimeStamp

1. video time: 489150134353920.000000 hostTime: 2026048145326080.000000  videoTimeScale: 241500000.000000 rateScalar: 1.000000 videoRefreshPeriod: 4028320.000000
2. video Time: 489150201462784.000000 hostTime: 2026048279543808.000000  videoTimeScale: 241500000.000000 rateScalar: 0.999985 videoRefreshPeriod: 4028320.000000
3. video Time: 489156643913728.000000 hostTime: 2026074988871680.000000  videoTimeScale: 241500000.000000 rateScalar: 1.000000 videoRefreshPeriod: 4028320.000000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CVTimeStamp`s are explained in the [CVTimeStamp Reference Document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CVTimeRef/Reference/reference.html). The `videoTimeScale` is the number of units that a second is divided into. So for 30 fps video, it would need to be at least 30 (though it could be any multiple of 30 - 60, 120, 30000, etc.). The `videoTime` is the time in the timescale where the current frame (or field) starts. So if your timebase is 30000, and you're on the 15th frame, your `videoTimeScale` would be 30000, and your `videoTime` would be 15000.

You can check that you've interpreted the value correctly by checking the `smpteTime` field and seeing if it matches what you expect. In the example above, it would be 0 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds, 15 frames (or 00:00:00:15).

Is there a reason why you can just use the OS's built-in video decoding facilities?

Comment: I can't use the built in decoding because my video file is encrypted.

Comment: smpteTime is always 0 (all values) Your explanation makes sense however, the data I receive does not. Based on your explanation I should see the same numbers for videoTime each time I play the video, correct? When I play my 1 second video the videotime differs each time I play the video. First run (first 2 frames requested)
video Time: 490954255499264
video Time: 490954456825856
second run (first 2 frames requested)
video Time: 491057066278912
video Time: 491057200496640

Comment: *CVTimeStamps are explained in the CVTimeStamp Reference Document.* - No, they really aren't.  That document does a very poor job of explaining the meaning of the fields.

Comment: @finnw More information is needed to properly answer this question any further. Which parameter are the values listed in the original post? The `timestampNow` or the `timestampOut`? Also, what are the flags for the timestamps? If the `kCVTimeStampSMPTETimeValid` flag is clear, then the SMPTE time won't be valid. But you might be able to call [`CVDisplayLinkTranslateTime()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CVDisplayLinkRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010025-CH2-SW16) to get it.

Comment: I can't find the [CVTimeStamp Reference Document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CVTimeRef/Reference/reference.html) anywhere. Are there any mirrors?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question, CVDisplayLink is woefully underdocumented, and I had to do a lot of reading and experimentation to figure it out. First off, you should read http://litherum.blogspot.com/2021/05/understanding-cvdisplaylink.html which gives a good overview of the fields. As explained there, at its core CVDisplayLink gives you access to the display clock (although Apple tries very hard to obscure this fact), and a way to convert between it and the system monotonic clock. The display clock is conceptually vsync-timed, and after one vsync, has incremented by the videoRefreshPeriod.

But things are a little more nuanced than that. You might think that the CVDisplayLink callback is called at the start of every vsync. That is unfortunately not the case. As described in https://thume.ca/2017/12/09/cvdisplaylink-doesnt-link-to-your-display/ and https://twitter.com/natbro/status/939857260313899008#m, on modern osx (10.11+) the callback actually happens *halfway* between the vsync events. (On older versions of osx, it was indeed close to the beginning however).

As a consequence, the `outTime` parameter of your displayLink is not actually guaranteed to be the the time of the next vsync. Instead, on modern osx it's the vsync *after that*. (On older osx, it is actually the next vsync though). I believe the thinking is that CVDisplayLink assumes you will take slightly under 1 vsync length to render your frame, so since on modern osx it calls you in the middle of the vsync, the target it gives you is 2 vsyncs ahead.

The `inTime` parameter is supposed to be the moment that the callback was triggered. However interestingly, while the hosttime is indeed this, the videoTime of `inTime` instead corresponds exactly to moment of the last vsync. At least as of osx 13.5, it seems that the video time has the stronger property that it will never be incremented in a resolution smaller than the video refresh period. (I would not rely on this behavior to be future-proof though, because nothing in apple docs guarantee it can't be).

Here is sample code that shows you exactly when the CVDisplayLink is fired within the vsync period. It does this on the assumption that videoTime of `inTime` corresponds to the last vsync. This can be converted to host time to give you the monotonic host-time of last vsync.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreVideo/CoreVideo.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <mach/mach_time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>


CVDisplayLinkRef _link;

CVReturn MyDisplayCallback(CVDisplayLinkRef displayLink,
    const CVTimeStamp *inTime,
    const CVTimeStamp *outTime,
    CVOptionFlags flagsIn,
    CVOptionFlags *flagsOut,
    void *displayLinkContext) {

        uint64_t inVBase = inTime->videoTime;
        uint64_t inTBase = inTime->hostTime;
        
        CVTimeStamp inTstamp;
        inTstamp.videoTime = inTime->videoTime;
        inTstamp.videoTimeScale = inTime->videoTimeScale;
        inTstamp.flags = kCVTimeStampVideoTimeValid;
        CVTimeStamp outTstamp;
        outTstamp.flags = kCVTimeStampHostTimeValid;
        CVDisplayLinkTranslateTime(_link, &inTstamp, &outTstamp);
        
        uint64_t vsyncStartHostTime = outTstamp.hostTime;
        inTstamp.videoTime = inTime->videoTime + inTime->videoRefreshPeriod;
        
        CVDisplayLinkTranslateTime(_link, &inTstamp, &outTstamp);
        uint64_t vsyncEndHostTime = outTstamp.hostTime;
        printf("%.2f\n", ((double)(inTime->hostTime - vsyncStartHostTime))/(vsyncEndHostTime - vsyncStartHostTime));
        

        
        return kCVReturnSuccess;
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        CVDisplayLinkCreateWithCGDisplay(CGMainDisplayID(),&_link);
        CVDisplayLinkSetOutputCallback(_link, MyDisplayCallback, NULL);
        CVDisplayLinkStart(_link);
        CFRunLoopRun();
    }
}
```

So given all of this, if what you want to do is to find out when the last vsync happened or when the immediately next vsync will happen, you should not use the `outTime` for this purpose. The best way I can see (albeit relying on undocumented behavior) would be to take  `inTime` (rounding it to the nearest `displayRefreshPeriod` if you want to be future-proof) as the last vsync, then add refreshPeriod to get the next vsync. Since you can then convert the display time to host time, you could even set up your own timer [1] to go off at the actual vsync intervals.

Finally it should be noted there are some CoreVideo helper functions like CVGetHostClockFrequency(). These are basically just wrappers for you to avoid interfacing with mach_time_base directly [CVGetHostClockFrequency] just returns (1/(time_num/time_denom))*1e9, i.e. conversion factor from host seconds to mach_absolute_time ticks.

[1] https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2169/_index.html